# How to fire subscribe only when param or one key-value pair of query param changes

Tags: angular, typescript

i have the following scenario where i want to fire the subscribe only when either the params of the url has changed or `showList` changes in the query param.Rest of the query param `page=0&size=5&sort=name,asc` is only added for cases like reload or navigating back to the same url and also gets added after the `showList` queryParam got added which leads to the subscribe getting fired twice.

The route changes in the following manner is i click on showList button

```
http://localhost:8080/org/acount/param1/param2?showList=true
http://localhost:8080/org/acount/param1/param2?showList=true&page=0&size=5&sort=name,asc
```

The second navigation happens because when showList is true an api call is made to fetch the list of accounts and if api returns back a non-empty result then page, size, sort is set.

Route changes to this if hide button is pressed

```
http://localhost:8080/org/acount/param1/param2?showList=false
```

I need to handle cases like reload + when back button is pressed too.

I have implemented the following to handle the above case but i know it's not the best possible solution:

```
this.params_subscribe = combineLatest([this.activatedRoute.params, this.activatedRoute.queryParams]).pipe(
      map(results => ({ param: results[0], query: results[1] }))
    ).subscribe(result => {
      let show_list: boolean = (result.query.showList === 'true');
      if ((JSON.stringify(result.param) !== JSON.stringify(this.prevParam)) || (result.query.showList !== this.prevQueryParam.showList)) {
        if (!this.from_ui || result.query.showList !== 'false') {
          if (result.param.teamId && result.param.breadcrumb) {
            ...
          }
          else {
            this.initialize()
          }
        }
      }
      this.prevParam = result.param;
      this.prevQueryParam = result.query;
    });
```

`from_ui` is used to prevent the function call if query param has changed by clicking the hideList button which sets `showList` to false.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`distinceUntilChanged`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) operator with a custom comparator.

Try the following

```js
combineLatest([
  this.activatedRoute.params, 
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams
]).pipe(
  map(results => ({ param: results[0], query: results[1] })),
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) =>
    JSON.stringify(prev.result.param) === JSON.stringify(curr.result.param) &&
    prev.result.query.showList === curr.result.query.showList
  )
).subscribe(
  ...
);
```